# Content goes out from bootstrap 4 template

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

On mobile, the content goes out off the page, and the horizontal scrollbar shows up.

You can check my page on [this link](https://terko-arak.hu/adatkezelesi-tajekoztato).

```
<div class="custom_content col-md-12">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
          <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="<?php echo $host; ?>" title="Kezdőlap">Kezdőlap</a></li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="<?php echo $host; ?>/<?php echo $pageSeo; ?>" title="<?php echo $pageTitle; ?>"><?php echo $pageTitle; ?></a></li>
          </ol>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <h1 class="page_title"><?php echo $pageTitle; ?></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="content"><?php GetContent($siteID); ?></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please [read the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#how-it-works). **"Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be immediate children of rows."**

Comment: Sorry, im not good in english. Can you show me a sample code?

Comment: The docs have plenty of examples.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Place your container tag out to row and col tags.
It should be like:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
</div>
</div></div>
```

It will fix it!

In other cases, follow below:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Add this tag in your code, and the page will be responsive based on the screen size.

Comment: It is on the page.  I tryed that  html structure you writed, bot it was the same. I dont understand.

Comment: Follow the below changes to your HTML file:

Comment: Step 1: Remove the <div class="content"> tag and its end tag </div>, (inside where you placed your contents - after Main heading "Adatkezelési tájékoztató".)

Comment: Step 2: Add attribute style={width:fit-content} inside body open tag.

Comment: That's it,Now it will work fine in any size display. Don't forget to give me an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You required to add one additional div with class `col` right after the row.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="custom_content col-md-12">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
          <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="<?php echo $host; ?>" title="Kezdőlap">Kezdőlap</a></li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item">
              <a href="<?php echo $host; ?>/<?php echo $pageSeo; ?>" title="<?php echo $pageTitle; ?>">
                <?php echo $pageTitle; ?>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ol>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <h1 class="page_title">
          <?php echo $pageTitle; ?>
        </h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="content">
          <?php GetContent($siteID); ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I added it, but still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<section class="custom_content">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
                    <ol class="breadcrumb">
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="<?php echo $host; ?>" title="Kezdőlap">Kezdőlap</a></li>
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="<?php echo $host; ?>/<?php echo $pageSeo; ?>" title="<?php echo $pageTitle; ?>"><?php echo $pageTitle; ?></a></li>
                    </ol>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <h1 class="page_title"><?php echo $pageTitle; ?></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="content"><?php GetContent($siteID); ?></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Your markup is wrong! As you didn't provide CSS code I have only fixed your layout.
 You should've used `.container > .row > .col-*-*`

- Containers provide a means to center and horizontally pad your site’s contents. Use .container for a responsive pixel width or .container-fluid for width: 100% across all viewport and device sizes.
- Rows are wrappers for columns. Each column has horizontal padding (called a gutter) for controlling the space between them. This padding is then counteracted on the rows with negative margins. This way, all the content in your columns is visually aligned down the left side.
- In a grid layout, content must be placed within columns and only columns may be immediate children of rows.

For reference go through [bootstrap grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/)